# Other code to use other than this "Util.fnDateRange()" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

A colleague wrote a view that needs changing; the problem is I was not there when it was made, so I do not know it inside out as if I coded this SQL view.

My colleague created a view and used CTEs to grab data faster. This is the CTE I'm having trouble with

```
vDateRange AS 
(  
SELECT  
    Date,  
    Year,  
    Month,  
    Day,  
    DayOfWeek  
FROM  
    Util.fnDateRange('2017-08-17', '2017-08-22')  
)
```

so as you can see this view will only get data from that date range, can someone show me how I can grab FROM something else instead of the `Util.fnDateRange()` because this CTE is used so many times in the view I can't just comment it out.

Comment: Sorry i'm using SQLServer

Comment: What do you mean by "grab FROM something" - from a table?

Comment: @halfer No to grab a date without grabbing from a table, my colleague is using this CTE like a class as someone would in Object Oriented Programming

Comment: OK, that's even less clear. If you do want to get dates ranges from something, but that something is not a table or a CTE, then what is that thing? Why can't you use this CTE? Perhaps you could show the larger query, to explain further what you actually are trying to do?

Comment: it's ok i set the range to an acceptable one where we can query the data we need @halfer

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query by using the range like this instead:

```
Util.fnDateRange('01-01-2014', GETUTCDATE())
```

now i can get from 2014 till the date of today.